# Batch producing reports

Tags: c#, report

We create 4k+ PDF reports every day to go out to customers the report is the same for every customer but perimeters within change (customers previous days orders). Currently we use crystal reports to create these reports but it doesn't work very well with multi threading as far as my knowledge extends and results in COM errors so for this reason its just ran in a for loop and takes about 2-3 hours to run.

I'm looking at improving this process as it really should take this long to create a simple PDF. My first thought is load the customers data in memory map this to a HTML template and then use something like IronPDF to convert the HTML to PDF.

Does anyone else do anything similar to this? if so what is your process in managing batch processing reports?

Comment: recommendations of libraries/external resources are off topic. problems with COM and multithreading are very on-topic, but in this case please share your code, with details about errors we need to address. if you have performance problems and an idea for a faster solution, try it and "run your horses". blatant advert (I am not affiliated): iTextSharp will be fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Crystal report automation tools listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched). At least one of them can handle your scenario. The whole process should take ~5 minutes.